# How to run edited monkey talk script

Tags: monkeytalk

Am newbie to Monkey talk. as i have created one monkey script but in the middle i have added some validation stuff to my recorded script but don't know how can u execute the edited script from monkey talk.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save the mtfile.mt with the same name mtfile.js and call 
Script mtfile.js Run from another mt file

Answer (score 0):

Use following command in 2nd mt file:

```
Script sample.mt Run
```